# How can a β,γ-unsaturated ketone be converted to 1-pyrroline?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds, c-c-addition

I am working towards a natural product. Presented are three intermediate compounds. After oxidation of the hydroxyl to a carbonyl, I want to introduce an imino-nitrogen atom into the structure. This way, an imino bond creates a five-membered ring, and the double bond disappears.

What reagent(s) should I choose for this type of reaction, and what does the reaction mechanism look like?

[image]

Comment: This is a tricky. You can't go with something like AcONH4/AcOH because you have other centres that can react, including a second enone (though presumably less reactive due to hindrance). I would be inclined to consider a two step process with 1eq of the anion of trifluoroacetamide or t-butylcarbamate followed by a deprotection to unmask the amine.

Comment: You may find the following paper interesting:
Reduction of Oximes and Aliphatic Nitro Compounds to Imines for further in situ Reactions: a Novel Synthesis of Pyrroles and Pyrrolin-2-ones. Barton, D. H. R.; Motherwell, W. B.; Simon, E. S.; Zard, S. Z. J. Chem. Soc., Perkin Trans. I 1986, 2243.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest two possible approaches. [Narasaka, et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403905003412) have effected similar cyclizations photochemically. I prefer to start with the allylic alcohol **1** to avoid complications with oxime formation. Formation of the bis acetate **2b** is not a problem. However, given the greater acidity of oximes relative to alcohols does not preclude the formation of oxime acetate **2a**. In the photolysis the naphthalene serves as a sensitizer while 1,4-cyclohexadiene functions as a hydrogen atom donor. The addition of hydrogen is likely from the convex face as shown. If not, after saponification of acetate **3b** and Swern oxidation, base equilibration would likely lead to ketone **4**.  
Alternatively, a Barton-type radical cyclization (**5** --> **3a**) might be considered. 
**ADDENDUM:** Direct photolysis of a structure similar to **5** without Bu<sub>3</sub>SnH has been achieved. See ref 2.

[image]
1) M. Kitamura, Y. Mori and K Narasaka, *[Tetrahedron Letters](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403905003412)*, **2005**, *46*, 2373.
2) F. Gagosz and S. Z. Zard, [*Synlett.*, **1999**, 1978](https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/pdf/10.1055/s-1999-2971.pdf).